# How do you implement seeking using the AudioStreamer sample application as a base?

Tags: iphone, streaming

I need to play some **audio** streaming contents on iPhone, but there are some options and problems I can't solve:

#### 1. http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html

It is a library provided by Matt Gallagher, but I saw the **Limited scope**, and I would play
**a single song**, not a radio station.

#### 2. Suggestion from zonble

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zonble.net/MIDI/orz.mp3"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
```

But I need streaming for each "single song".

#### 3. Using MPMoviePlayerController to wrapper.

Since the Class update new method, and

```
@interface MyAudioStreamer : UIViewController {
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp ;
}
```

instead of `[self addSubview:mp.view]` I use my own **xib file** to implement **play** and
**stop** methods, but in this case, I have no idea to implement seekForward or seekBackward.

Is there any good idea to do AudioStreamer?

==== Update ====

after google 'AVPlayer' ,i used **3. Using MPMoviePlayerController to wrapper.** to implement a auidoStreamer-like player ,there is something to share :

**1.'playbackDidFinished' state**
there're 2 conditions : a song did finished and play next song or a song interrupt by   user press stop or exception, i used enum to filter my state.

**2 multi-task playing your song in background**
reference from https:// devforums.apple.com/message/264397

and if iOS SDK update, the solution might be changed because method would be diplicated. so i suggest to read library provided by Matt Gallagher.

anyone who konws when the library have no codec match download item (for example, my item encode by .AAC 128-bit and the library not support or at most .AAC 64-bit), what happen would the player be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse the [icy meta data](http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html) yourself, or if you're using iOS 4.0 you can playback using an `AVPlayer` and observe the timed metadata to discover the song boundaries and titles.